# Cypress with Istanbul is not generating code coverage reports

Tags: vue.js, jenkins, automated-tests, cypress, istanbul

I have VueJS app and Cypress for testing. I need to have code coverage info.

Running tests in Cypress is generating seemingly correct .nyc_output/out.json file with numbers how many times some lines were executed.

How to generate correct report?

Problem is that `npx nyc report` says that everything is 0%
[image]

```
tree .nyc_output/
```

[image]

Sample from the out.json where numbers are different from zero
[image]

Comment: Did you follow the code coverage guide? https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage.html

Comment: Coverage guide is followed and it all works except the report is not generated.

Comment: Any updates? I am facing the same issue. Getting out.json as an empty object.

Comment: One guy in our team is able to generate reports on one machine. Did not find any correlation or reason why it does not work otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

For me, downgrading nyc version solved it

```
npx nyc@13.3.0 report
```